# SQL Server Broker Service Target Transmission Queue issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, service-broker

I've implemented **two SSB across two different instances**. They are **data push** pattern based on **asynchronous triggers**.

I am using **SQL Server Enterprise 2008 R2**, version info is found below

My SQL Version is Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      10.0.4064.0
 Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      10.0.4064.0
 Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.1.7601.17514
 Microsoft MSXML      3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.0.8112.16421
 Microsoft .NET Framework      2.0.50727.5446
 Operating System      6.1.7601

1. My queue is **RETENTION** set to **off**.
2. **Sender Queue and sys.TransmissionQueue** are **empty**.
3. **Target Queue** is **empty** ,but **Target sys.transmissionqueue** contains the **5000 messages** I **sent**.
4. **The table**, **data** is **inserted** in @Target DB is **locked**. "When I **select** with **nolock** the **5000 records** appears"
5. **Profiler** shows

@**Sender**

Broker:Conversation STARTED_OUTBOUND

Broker:Conversation CONVERSING

Broker:Message Classify

Broker:Remote Message Acknowledgement

Broker:Conversation Group

@**Reciever**

Broker:Conversation DISCONNECTED_OUTBOUND

Broker:Conversation Group

Broker:Message Classify

Broker:Remote Message Acknowledgement

Broker:Message Undeliverable This message was dropped because it could not be dispatched on time. State: 1

1. **SSBDIAGNOSE** shows **no error**.

I've used Rusanu's blog entry to troubleshoot the problem ,but I think my situation is different!

Hope anyone could help :)

Comment: What is happening to make Messages stuck at target sys.transmission queue?
Why the table is locked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like your target processing is receving messages, responding with and EndDialog, but not committing the transaction. This would explain the symptoms you describe (data is inserted but locked, target transmission queue has 5k messages not being sent). Can you confirm that the target processing is properly committing and ending the transactions?

Comment: Yeah Remus, it worked fine. I forgot to put the commit after End Conversation.
Thanks